# Framer Motion - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Easing'. TS232

Tags: typescript, framer-motion

I'm using Framer Motion 5.3.3 to do some animation for my web page. I'm trying to use the easing option for Motion's `useTransform` hook. See this example taken from the useTransform [docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/##usetransform):

```
const xRange = [-200, -100, 100, 200]
const opacityRange = [0, 1, 1, 0]
const opacity = useTransform(x, xRange, opacityRange, {clamp: true, ease: "linear"})
```

Gives error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Easing | Easing[]'.
```

But in the source code I see that "linear" is included in the type definition for [`Easing`](https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/0a7416929cb90fd6f88adb06b5937eee2971e121/src/types.ts#L74). So why doesn't this work? What's the correct way to use `ease`?

```js
export type Easing =
    | [number, number, number, number]
    | "linear"
    | "easeIn"
    | "easeOut"
    | "easeInOut"
    | "circIn"
    | "circOut"
    | "circInOut"
    | "backIn"
    | "backOut"
    | "backInOut"
    | "anticipate"
    | EasingFunction
```

Comment: Looks like `ease` type is widen to `string`. You can use `as const` assertion to prevent this: `ease: "linear" as const` or even `{clamp: true, ease: "linear"} as const`

Comment: Hmm neither seem to work for me.  The later gives error:  ```Argument of type '{ readonly clamp: true; readonly ease: "linear"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransformOptions<number>'. Types of property 'ease' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Easing | Easing[]'.ts(2345)```

Comment: `{clamp: true, ease: "linear" as const}` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope that does not work either, gives error: ```Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Easing | Easing[]'.ts(2322)```

Answer (score 0):

The easing definition of the TransformOption is using popmotion library.

In the your file :

```
import { linear } from '@popmotion/easing';
```

Then

```
 const y = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 500], [0, 300], {ease: linear})
```